# If $X_1, X_2, \ldots$ are iid with mean $m>0$, and $\tau = min(n: X_1+\ldots+X_n >k)$, how to show $E(\tau) \geq \frac{k}{m}$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Suppose we have that $X_1, X_2, \ldots$ are iid with mean $m>0$. Let $k>0$ be a positive number. Then, suppose we define $\tau = min(n: X_1+\ldots+X_n >k)$. I would like to show that $E(\tau) \geq \frac{k}{m}$. I am looking over Chernoff's bound, and the central limit theorem, but cannot get either of them to apply. Does anyone have any hints as to what I can do? Thanks.

Comment: Note that $S_\tau>k$ almost surely, by definition, and that $$S_\tau=\sum_{n\geqslant1}X_n\mathbf 1_{S_{n-1}\leqslant k}=\sum_{n\geqslant1}X_n\mathbf 1_{\tau\geqslant n},$$ hence, using the independence of $X_n$ and $S_{n-1}$ for each $n$, one sees that $$k<E(S_\tau)=\sum_{n\geqslant1}E(X_n)P(S_{n-1}\leqslant k)=m\sum_{n\geqslant1}P(\tau\geqslant n)=mE(\tau).$$

Comment: @Did So basically $S_\tau$ here is the sum of the random variables $X_i$ assuming they haven't hit $k$ as a sum yet?

Comment: Correction: the middle formula in my comment may be wrong when $P(X_i\geqslant0)\ne1$, fortunately it is not needed as written. To be complete, use $$S_\tau=\sum_{n\geqslant1}X_n\mathbf 1_{S_1\leqslant k,\ldots,S_{n-1}\leqslant k}=\sum_{n\geqslant1}X_n\mathbf 1_{\tau\geqslant n},$$ and proceed as before, using the independence of $X_n$ and $(S_1,\ldots,S_{n-1})$.

Comment: Is $\tau$ a stopping time? Probably look into one of the stopping time theorems